# Prometheus & cadvisor & k8s / "image" label with Empty values

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, cadvisor

In Prometheus expression browsers, executing "container_cpu_usage_seconds_total metric" got results with different labels in different k8s clusters.

cluster 1 (k8s v1.15.9):

```
container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container="POD",container_name="POD",cpu="total",endpoint="https-metrics",id="/kubepods/besteffort/pod00xxxxx-ef9f-4959-b2cf-95e9c6dba800/bbff610aeeb79874c69228068f07b9c3a395a3933b33387fd681ef91aa188897",image="reg.k8s.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.1",instance="192.168.110.120:10250",job="kubelet",name="k8s_POD_guestbook-ui-57d98b678-w5csk_argo-cd_0068264c-ef9f-4959-b2cf-95e9c6dba800_0",namespace="argo-cd",node="k8s-w5",pod="guestbook-ui-57d98b678-w5csk",pod_name="guestbook-ui-57d98b678-w5csk",service="kubelet"}
```

cluster 2（k8s v1.18.10）:

```
container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{cpu="total", endpoint="https-metrics", id="/kubepods/besteffort/pod07a4289a-9ae4-42fd-a7d5-5fe7d8680071", instance="192.168.120.10:10250", job="kubelet", metrics_path="/metrics/cadvisor", namespace="eds", node="cluster-master-1", pod="kong-7dc748b8d5-5x5qf", service="kube-kube-prometheus-stack-kubelet"}
```

No "**image**" "**container**" labels found in the second cluster.
How can I configure the second one to make it have the missing labels?

A difference exists in their **scrape_configs**.
The second one doesn't have **metric_relabel_configs**. Does the metric_relabel_configs affects the available labels?

```
  metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__name__, image]
    separator: ;
    regex: container_([a-z_]+);
    replacement: $1
    action: drop
  - source_labels: [__name__]
    separator: ;
    regex: container_cpu_usage_seconds_total|container_memory_usage_bytes|container_memory_cache|container_network_.+_bytes_total|container_memory_working_set_bytes
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
```

When I executed the curl command in the second cluster, in fact the result had **image** and **container** labels, but with **Empty value**.

```
curl -k --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"  https://[k8s_ip]:10250/metrics/cadvisor
```

Result:

```
container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container="",cpu="total",id="/kubepods/besteffort/pod07a4289a-9ae4-42fd-a7d5-5fe7d8680071",image="",name="",namespace="eds",pod="kong-7dc748b8d5-5x5qf"} 738.009191131 1617976437601
```

Answer (score 0):

Your symptoms are somewhat similar to [this issue](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/1932).

> The high-level symptom is that `curl /metrics` returns blank for image, namespace, etc.
>
> It appears that kubelet's view of the universe has diverged significantly from Docker's hence it does not have the metadata to tag container metrics.

In my case I was running Docker with a nonstandard root directory, and telling kubelet this explictly via `--docker-root` fixed the problem.